# Back button goes back of 2 activities instead of 1

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, back-button, back

as subject my app goes back of 2 activities when I push back button. This is the overrided back button of the activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mainNavMenu != null && mainNavMenu.getDrawerLayout().isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        mainNavMenu.getDrawerLayout().closeDrawers();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

This is the activities stack before the press of the button:

```
Task id #300
* TaskRecord{3470ba7b #300 A=com.package.example U=0 sz=3}
  userId=0 effectiveUid=u0a199 mCallingUid=u0a199 mCallingPackage=com.package.example
  affinity=com.package.example
  intent={act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.package.example/.view.SplashScreenActivity}
  realActivity=com.package.example/.view.SplashScreenActivity
  autoRemoveRecents=false isPersistable=true numFullscreen=3 taskType=0 mTaskToReturnTo=1
  rootWasReset=false mNeverRelinquishIdentity=true mReuseTask=false
  Activities=[ActivityRecord{d9eeb4e u0 com.package.example/.view.MainActivity t300}, ActivityRecord{2017cfc8 u0 com.package.example/.view.JobDetailsActivity t300}, ActivityRecord{3da3f636 u0 com.package.example/.view.WebActivity t300}]
  askedCompatMode=false inRecents=true isAvailable=true
  lastThumbnail=android.graphics.Bitmap@22f31098 lastThumbnailFile=/data/system/recent_images/300_task_thumbnail.png
  hasBeenVisible=true firstActiveTime=1517840356492 lastActiveTime=1517840356492 (inactive for 4s)
  * Hist #2: ActivityRecord{3da3f636 u0 com.package.example/.view.WebActivity t300}
      packageName=com.package.example processName=com.package.example
      launchedFromUid=10199 launchedFromPackage=com.package.example userId=0
      app=ProcessRecord{21ce55f9 17355:com.package.example/u0a199}
      Intent { cmp=com.package.example/.view.WebActivity (has extras) }
      frontOfTask=false task=TaskRecord{3470ba7b #300 A=com.package.example U=0 sz=3}
      taskAffinity=com.package.example
      realActivity=com.package.example/.view.WebActivity
      baseDir=/data/app/com.package.example-2/base.apk
      dataDir=/data/data/com.package.example
      stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true mActivityType=0
      compat={480dpi} labelRes=0x7f0d001f icon=0x7f0c0000 theme=0x7f0e0007
      config={0 1.0 222mcc99mnc it_IT ldltr sw360dp w360dp h615dp 480dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.6}
      resultTo=ActivityRecord{2017cfc8 u0 com.package.example/.view.JobDetailsActivity t300} resultWho=null resultCode=1117
      taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" color=ffadd44b
      launchFailed=false launchCount=1 lastLaunchTime=-4s170ms
      haveState=false icicle=null
      state=RESUMED stopped=false delayedResume=false finishing=false
      keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=true sleeping=false idle=true
      fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=0
      frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
      mActivityType=APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_TYPE
      waitingVisible=false nowVisible=true lastVisibleTime=-3s325ms
  * Hist #1: ActivityRecord{2017cfc8 u0 com.package.example/.view.JobDetailsActivity t300}
      packageName=com.package.example processName=com.package.example
      launchedFromUid=10199 launchedFromPackage=com.package.example userId=0
      app=ProcessRecord{21ce55f9 17355:com.package.example/u0a199}
      Intent { cmp=com.package.example/.view.JobDetailsActivity (has extras) }
      frontOfTask=false task=TaskRecord{3470ba7b #300 A=com.package.example U=0 sz=3}
      taskAffinity=com.package.example
      realActivity=com.package.example/.view.JobDetailsActivity
      baseDir=/data/app/com.package.example-2/base.apk
      dataDir=/data/data/com.package.example
      stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true mActivityType=0
      compat={480dpi} labelRes=0x7f0d001f icon=0x7f0c0000 theme=0x7f0e0007
      config={0 1.0 222mcc99mnc it_IT ldltr sw360dp w360dp h615dp 480dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.6}
      taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" color=ffadd44b
      launchFailed=false launchCount=1 lastLaunchTime=-33s92ms
      haveState=false icicle=null
      state=STOPPING stopped=false delayedResume=false finishing=false
      keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=false sleeping=false idle=true
      fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=0
      frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
      mActivityType=APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_TYPE
      waitingVisible=false nowVisible=false lastVisibleTime=-32s196ms
  * Hist #0: ActivityRecord{d9eeb4e u0 com.package.example/.view.MainActivity t300}
      packageName=com.package.example processName=com.package.example
      launchedFromUid=10199 launchedFromPackage=com.package.example userId=0
      app=ProcessRecord{21ce55f9 17355:com.package.example/u0a199}
      Intent { flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.package.example/.view.MainActivity (has extras) }
      frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{3470ba7b #300 A=com.package.example U=0 sz=3}
      taskAffinity=com.package.example
      realActivity=com.package.example/.view.MainActivity
      baseDir=/data/app/com.package.example-2/base.apk
      dataDir=/data/data/com.package.example
      stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true mActivityType=0
      compat={480dpi} labelRes=0x7f0d001f icon=0x7f0c0000 theme=0x7f0e0007
      config={0 1.0 222mcc99mnc it_IT ldltr sw360dp w360dp h615dp 480dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.6}
      taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" color=ffadd44b
      launchFailed=false launchCount=0 lastLaunchTime=-2m18s969ms
      haveState=true icicle=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=3876]
      state=STOPPED stopped=true delayedResume=false finishing=false
      keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=false sleeping=false idle=true
      fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=0
      frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
      mActivityType=APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_TYPE
      waitingVisible=false nowVisible=false lastVisibleTime=-2m18s47ms

Running activities (most recent first):
  TaskRecord{3470ba7b #300 A=icom.package.example U=0 sz=3}
    Run #2: ActivityRecord{3da3f636 u0 icom.package.example/.view.WebActivity t300}
    Run #1: ActivityRecord{2017cfc8 u0 icom.package.example/.view.JobDetailsActivity t300}
    Run #0: ActivityRecord{d9eeb4e u0 icom.package.example/.view.MainActivity t300}

mResumedActivity: ActivityRecord{3da3f636 u0 icom.package.example/.view.WebActivity t300}
mLastPausedActivity: ActivityRecord{2017cfc8 u0 icom.package.example/.view.JobDetailsActivity t300}
```

There are 3 Running activities.
When I press back button this is the stack:

```
Task id #300
* TaskRecord{3470ba7b #300 A=icom.package.example U=0 sz=1}
  userId=0 effectiveUid=u0a199 mCallingUid=u0a199 mCallingPackage=icom.package.example
  affinity=icom.package.example
  intent={act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=icom.package.example/.view.SplashScreenActivity}
  realActivity=icom.package.example/.view.SplashScreenActivity
  autoRemoveRecents=false isPersistable=true numFullscreen=1 taskType=0 mTaskToReturnTo=1
  rootWasReset=false mNeverRelinquishIdentity=true mReuseTask=false
  Activities=[ActivityRecord{d9eeb4e u0 icom.package.example/.view.MainActivity t300}]
  askedCompatMode=false inRecents=true isAvailable=true
  lastThumbnail=android.graphics.Bitmap@22f31098 lastThumbnailFile=/data/system/recent_images/300_task_thumbnail.png
  hasBeenVisible=true firstActiveTime=1517840391154 lastActiveTime=1517840391154 (inactive for 4s)
  * Hist #0: ActivityRecord{d9eeb4e u0 icom.package.example/.view.MainActivity t300}
      packageName=icom.package.example processName=icom.package.example
      launchedFromUid=10199 launchedFromPackage=icom.package.example userId=0
      app=ProcessRecord{21ce55f9 17355:icom.package.example/u0a199}
      Intent { flg=0x10008000 cmp=icom.package.example/.view.MainActivity (has extras) }
      frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{3470ba7b #300 A=icom.package.example U=0 sz=1}
      taskAffinity=icom.package.example
      realActivity=icom.package.example/.view.MainActivity
      baseDir=/data/app/icom.package.example-2/base.apk
      dataDir=/data/data/icom.package.example
      stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true mActivityType=0
      compat={480dpi} labelRes=0x7f0d001f icon=0x7f0c0000 theme=0x7f0e0007
      config={0 1.0 222mcc99mnc it_IT ldltr sw360dp w360dp h615dp 480dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.6}
      taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" color=ffadd44b
      launchFailed=false launchCount=0 lastLaunchTime=-2m54s257ms
      haveState=false icicle=null
      state=RESUMED stopped=false delayedResume=false finishing=false
      keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=true sleeping=false idle=true
      fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=0
      frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
      mActivityType=APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_TYPE
      waitingVisible=false nowVisible=true lastVisibleTime=-4s367ms

Running activities (most recent first):
  TaskRecord{3470ba7b #300 A=icom.package.example U=0 sz=1}
    Run #0: ActivityRecord{d9eeb4e u0 icom.package.example/.view.MainActivity t300}

mResumedActivity: ActivityRecord{d9eeb4e u0 icom.package.example/.view.MainActivity t300}
mLastPausedActivity: ActivityRecord{2017cfc8 u0 icom.package.example/.view.JobDetailsActivity t300 f}
```

As you can see there is just 1 activity left, and I do not why it happens.

Comment: Try without `super.onBackPressed();`

Comment: It does not work, it does not go back at all

Comment: are you not adding flags when starting the activity ? Maybe you have a "noHistory" in your manifest ?

Comment: No "noHistory" in the manifest. if there was "noHistory", why I see the activity in the stack? That's it I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

```
private void moveBack() {
    //check for entry count
    if (fragmentManager != null && fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I use fragments, but I did not understand your answer. Can you explain more please?

Comment: for moving back just use the fragmentmanager.popbackstack() option can you please share your fragment code, so I can explain you better

Comment: actually the activity jumped is not fragmentactivity, it is AppCompatActivity

Comment: call this moveback method in your onBackPressed()

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please add relevant comments to your answer so that it is easy to understand why you posted code and what the code does differently for the Asker...

Comment: same behaviour, it always goes to the "else" part.